# Get RestSharp deserializator used for deserializing response

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, restsharp

When I make call using ressharp

```
response = client.Execute<SomeClass>(request);
```

I need to know which deserializer restsharp used inside to deserialize this responce.
I know that restsharp determine deserializer based on the Content Type returned by the server.

I need something like this

```
var deserializator = responce.GetUsedDeserializator();
```

or even

```
var deserializator = restclient.GetDeserializatorForContentType(responce.ContentType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thereisn't simple way to do it.The only way I found is extracting restsharp source code.

```
public static class RestSharpExtensions
{
    private static readonly Regex structuredSyntaxSuffixRegex = new Regex("\\+\\w+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    private static Dictionary<string, IDeserializer> contentTypeToDeserializerMap = new Dictionary
        <string, IDeserializer>
    {
        {"application/json", new JsonDeserializer()},
        {"application/xml", new XmlDeserializer()},
        {"text/json", new JsonDeserializer()},
        {"text/x-json", new JsonDeserializer()},
        {"text/javascript", new JsonDeserializer()},
        {"text/xml", new XmlDeserializer()},
        {"*+json",  new JsonDeserializer()},
        {"*+xml", new XmlDeserializer()},
        {"*",  new XmlDeserializer()}
    };


    public static IDeserializer GetDeserializer(this IRestResponse restResponse)
    {
        var contentType = restResponse.ContentType;
        if (contentType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contentType");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) && contentTypeToDeserializerMap.ContainsKey("*"))
            return contentTypeToDeserializerMap["*"];
        int length = contentType.IndexOf(';');
        if (length > -1)
            contentType = contentType.Substring(0, length);
        if (contentTypeToDeserializerMap.ContainsKey(contentType))
            return contentTypeToDeserializerMap[contentType];
        Match match = structuredSyntaxSuffixRegex.Match(contentType);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string key = "*" + match.Value;
            if (contentTypeToDeserializerMap.ContainsKey(key))
                return contentTypeToDeserializerMap[key];
        }
        if (contentTypeToDeserializerMap.ContainsKey("*"))
            return contentTypeToDeserializerMap["*"];
        return (IDeserializer)null;
    }

}
```